# Encoding attribute and xml file size

Tags: xml, xslt, filesize

I am running the identity transformation bellow on a 11 MB xml file and it results in an 5.5 MB file. 
I am using Saxon 9.4.0.6.
If I add an encoding attribute to the output element, the result file size stays at 11 MB.

With encoding:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="Value" indent="no" encoding="utf-16"/>
```

Without encoding:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="Value" indent="no"/>
```

Where is the big difference comming from?
Thank you

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="Value" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from the fact that [ASCII characters take 1 byte in UTF-8, but 2 bytes in UTF-16](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: and if you don't specify an output encoding, the default is UTF-8.